# Add a new global variable in smarty? available on all pages. (prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I am looking to add a global variable in smarty.

I added css styles with {$urls.css_url} in stylesheep.tpl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$urls.css_url}my.css">
```

It works very well, except that if I put the shop on debug mode, I have this error:

```
ContextErrorException in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 393: Notice: Undefined index: css_url
```

What does that mean? that this variable will not be available in smarty?, so if I put the cache, it will not be loaded?

How to make variable {$ urls.css_url} available with smarty? everywhere on the site?

Which code should I put and where to put it so that the variable (url_css)  remains available in debug mode?

Thanks for your help

---

Thank you for your help, you have a high level compared to me.

In fact the variable is already defined and is available everywhere.

In frontcontroler.php, I had this:

```
$assign_array = array(
    'img_ps_url' => _PS_IMG_,
    'img_cat_url' => _THEME_CAT_DIR_,
    'img_lang_url' => _THEME_LANG_DIR_,
    'img_prod_url' => _THEME_PROD_DIR_,
    'img_manu_url' => _THEME_MANU_DIR_,
    'img_sup_url' => _THEME_SUP_DIR_,
    'img_ship_url' => _THEME_SHIP_DIR_,
    'img_store_url' => _THEME_STORE_DIR_,
    'img_col_url' => _THEME_COL_DIR_,
    'img_url' => _THEME_IMG_DIR_,
    'css_url' => _THEME_CSS_DIR_,
    'js_url' => _THEME_JS_DIR_,
    'pic_url' => _THEME_PROD_PIC_DIR_,
);
```

I then added the next line below to assign it in smarty.

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array('urls' => $urls));
```

The variable is displayed, no problem but if I put the shop in debug mode:

```
/* Debug only */
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
}
```

I always have this:

```
ContextErrorException in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 393: Notice: Undefined index: css_url
```

Does this indicate that there is no value? Why does its value disappear? (when I activate PS_MODE_DEV)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`{$urls.css_url}` means to retrieve the the css_url value from the urls array.

Also the Notice you receive means the variable has no value, so it can't work at all, so maybe what you think is correct, but what you see comes from other variable / hook.

---

**How to set a Smarty Variable**

In case you want to set a smarty variable you will have first to assign it.

You can do it through a module, controller or a TPL.

From a module or a controller it will be available as soon as you declare it. To print or to debug it.

So, for example if you add it in the `hookDisplayHeader` or in `actionFrontControllerSetMedia` hooks the variable will available where you want to use it.

Also, to assign the value in a module or controller you will have to use a code like this:

```
$urls = array (
    'css_url' => 'The URL to your CSS'
    ...
);
$this->context->smarty->assign(array('urls' => $urls));
```

Then you will be able to access it using `{$urls.css_url}`

---

**How to know the already defined variables in Smarty**

Enable the debug mode of your shop and then just add `{debug}` in any of your TPLs, this will show a Pop Up (remember to allow popups from your URL) with all the variables assigned to Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

Version: Prestashop 1.7.2.4

We are going to do this overriding a class, in this case the following file: classes/controller/FrontController.php, this file assigns global variables for Prestashop.

1. Create a file: override/classes/controller/FrontController.php
2. Copy all the contents from: classes/controller/FrontController.php to our recently created file.
3. Check the following line: 1444, there is a function called **getTemplateVarUrls()**, inside this function there is already a variable **css_url** that points to theme css default dir : /public_html/themes/theme_name/assets/css
4. If you want to create a custom url variable write the code there, i.e:

   ```
   public function getTemplateVarUrls()
   {
     $http = Tools::getCurrentUrlProtocolPrefix();
     $base_url = $this->context->shop->getBaseURL(true, true);

     //custom css url var points to a folder called "my_custom_css" in the root of the project
     $customCssFolderUrl = $base_url.'/my_customs_css';

     $urls = array(
       'base_url' => $base_url,
       'current_url' => $this->context->shop->getBaseURL(true, false).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
       'shop_domain_url' => $this->context->shop->getBaseURL(true, false),
       'custom_css_url' => $customCssFolderUrl ,
   );
   ```
5. After we finish all this steps we proceed to delete public_html/app/cache/prod/class_index.php file, this to prevent Prestashop from ignoring our new file, to read more about this: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors
6. Use your new variable: {$urls.custom_css_url} on any .tpl file

Hope this helps.